# Mac Os X Installer that copies contents from cd

Tags: xcode, macos, bash, installation, cd

I have to make an mac os x app that has some awful specifications. I managed to make the app but now I am stuck at the `installer` phase. I have to copy the app to the application folder (easy) from a cd (not dvd but a 700 mb cd keep that in mind) and 300 to 500 mb zip file, containing webpages and resources, in the app folder (AppName.app) and unarchive it there in a `www` folder.

I tried doing this with a `package installer` and a `shell script` unfortunately the script runs in a `sandbox` and I can't access the content form the cd.

I can't put the zip files in the install package because there is a windows and a linux installer that uses them too. So it's a shared resource.

I've tried different approaches to resolve this issue, none seemed to work.The only solution that is in my head right now is to make another app in `objective c` (that will run from the cd) witch will copy the real app and the zip file to the applications folder.

I must have an friendly executable installer for the app and that is my only desperate choice at the moment.
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the soulution:
Aparently the postscript is called with 4 params:

$1, $2, $3 and $4
$1 is the place your package installer (usulay its in the .mpkg executable folder you have to go down a few dirs in the herarchy)
$2 is the sanbox place of your installer
$3 is the aplication destinations or root (here I got both situations :-?? so I checked them up)
$4 is the root

so the path was something like this:
$1/../../../file.zip
unzip to
/Aplications/AppName.app/www/